# Can't turn python datasets library into an exe

Tags: pyinstaller, exe, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to convert my Python file into an executable (exe) using the auto-py-to-exe tool. However, when I run the generated exe, I encounter the following error: Link to error screenshot. As a result, the program crashes. I suspect the problem might be related to the import of the datasets library, but I'm not entirely sure. Has anyone experienced a similar issue with auto-py-to-exe and datasets library?

If you have any suggestions or solutions on how to fix this problem, please let me know.

I figured out the error is caused by the datasets library by excluding it and when i did it everything work.